# ForeigKey (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I create these tables and add one foreingkey in final, but executing watch this error:

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'despesas' already exists (SQL: create table `despesas` (`id_despesa` i
  nt unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `categoria` int unsigned not null, `descricao` varchar(255) not null, `valor_previsto`
 int not null, `valor_real` int not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collat
  e utf8_unicode_ci).

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'despesas' already exists.

Code:

```
Schema::create('despesas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_despesa');
            $table->integer('categoria')->unsigned();
            $table->string('descricao');
            $table->Integer('valor_previsto');
            $table->Integer('valor_real');
            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nome');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('despesas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the database, create and migrate it again. You had an exception while migrating, hence migrations table in your database is not up to date.

Comment: Yes, correct solucion! 
I think I've made some previous changes that damaged the table. Thanks

Comment: @IgorFaria make sure to flag answer as a correct if it helped =)